# Error : Stopped workout session cannot be restarted

Tags: ios, watchos-2, healthkit

I can start and stop a `HealthKit` workout session. But when I try to start a second workout after my first has stopped, I get the error:

> "workOutSession Error : Stopped workout session cannot be restarted"

How do I start the next `workout session` (after the first has been stopped) without closing down and restarting the app? I am using **Xcode 7.2,** **IOS9.2**
and **Watch OS 2.1**

Stopping from InterfaceController:

```
func startWorkout() {
    myExtensionConnectivity.startSession()
    myExtensionHealthKitManager.startWorkout()
    myExtensionConnectivity.sendStartUpdatingCommand()
    }

func stopWorkout() {
    myExtensionConnectivity.sendStopUpdatingCommand()
    myExtensionHealthKitManager.endWorkout()
    myExtensionConnectivity.stopSession()
    }
```

From HealthkitManager:

```
func endWorkout() {
    healthStore.endWorkoutSession(workoutSession)
}

func startWorkout() {
    healthStore.startWorkoutSession(workoutSession)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a new HKWorkoutSession instance before starting the second workout.  As the error message states, you may not re-start a stopped session.

Comment: Thanks! It should of been obvious, but sometimes that helps!